# Adding elements to a tuple when I know I shouldn't be able to

Tags: python, tuples

[Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/tuples.html) is one of many sources that says:

> You can't add elements to a tuple.

But it looks as if I was allowed to do just that. My code:

```
from string import find

def subStringMatchExact(target, key):
    t = (99,)
    location = find(target, key)
    while location != -1
        t += (location,)    # Why is this allowed?
        location = find(target, key, location + 1)
    return t

print subStringMatchExact("atgacatgcacaagtatgcat", "tg")
```

Output:

```
(99, 1, 6, 16)
```

This leads me to believe that I am not actually creating a tuple when I initialize `t`. Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are concatenating 2 tuples in a new one.
You are not modifying the original.

```
> a = (1,)
> b = a
> b == a
True
> a += (2,)
> b == a
False
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Should that have been obvious? I mean I guess it should have been based on the nature of tuple objects, but it looks a lot like it's adding an element to an existing tuple. I need to remove myself from that mindset :)

Comment: @Corey You can test yourself . For exemple, add a line ``print id(t)`` after the instruction ``t += (location,)    # Why is this allowed?`` and you will see that **t** points successively to different objects.

Comment: `tuple` is an immutable type, once created, can never change. So you can guess this behavior.

Comment: `string` is immutable type as well as a `tuple`, so why don't you wonder about `s1 += s2`? :)

Answer (score 3):

`t += (location,)` is a shorthand for `t = t + (location,)` so you are creating a new tuple instance and assigning that to t each time around the loop.

Comment: Note that `+=` *is* in fact an in-place-modification for some other types, including lists.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I was having trouble seeing the difference between using += on tuples and using it on lists.

Comment: In fact in using list I tend to use l.append() or l.extend()

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're just creating a new instance of a tuple and assigning it to `t`. It's not actually modifying the original `t` object.